# How to convert database entry string into another string

Tags: php

My database is connected to a game, and the database fields are populated with each player who buys a vehicle. The vehicle is then saved to the database once the player has brought it, and it saves the vehicles name as the game's actual name.. For Example lets say I brought a Dodge Charger, it would save the name of that as dodge_charger. I don't want the table I've done to display dodge_charger (or any other vehicle for that matter) just want to use some kind of array to replace the word automatically for example

```
array(
    "dodge_charger" => "Somenew Name", 
    "ford_gt" => "Another Newname", 
    "hyundai_xl" => "Yet Another New Name"
);
```

So the first word(with underscore) is what saves to the database, and second is what I want it to display in PHP, but the names of the vehicles will always be different as per vehicle purchased in-game. I don't want to just remove the Underscore using PHP it's more renaming it to whatever I choose as the second name.

If that makes sense?

Comment: How to you plan on renaming? will you loop through every entry and rename based on your needs  or is there an identifiable pattern we could regex for and then output will follow another regex pattern to do all this at once?

Comment: Treat the `car_name_label` as a token for localization, and then your token is "translated" into whatever you need. At the heart of this is a YAML structure is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table should be structured so that it has this layout:

**Table One: Users Cars**

*Columns:*

ID

UserID

Car ID

Car Name

**Table Two: Cars**

*Columns:*

Car ID

Car Type (dodge_charger, ford_gt)

This will allow the user to buy multiple cars of the same type (So they can have 2 dodge chargers)

Sorry to explain this a little further you store the ID of the Users Car entry into an array if you want to, then just grab that row when you need it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace` and `array_map`.
For example:

```
<?php


$translations = [
    'dodge_charger' => 'Somenew Name',
    'ford_gt' => 'Another Newname',
    'hyundai_xl' => 'Yet Another New Name'

];

$dbValues = array_map(
    function($str) use ($translations) {
        return str_replace(array_keys($translations), array_values($translations), $str);
    },
    $dbValues
);


print_r($dbValues);
```

This code does assume your values (from the database) that you want to replace are in an array. Eg :

```
[ 'dodge_charger',  'ford_gt', 'hyundai_xl', 'prius' ];
```